# Mojave kernel panic related to Slack?

Tags: mojave, kernel-panic

Macbook Pro 15" mid-2015, MacOs Mojave 10.14.6 (18G7016), 2 external displays (HDMI and Thunderbolt-to-HDMI adaptor)

On 2 consecutive days I've had kernel panics that have restarted my mac. IIRC, the apps that were open both times were:

- Slack
- Webstorm
- Chrome
- Outlook
- iTerm2
- Apple mail

The 2 logs in my Diagnostic Reports folder both have the text:

```
possible cause: unlocking an unlocked mutex or
spinlock"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-
4903.278.51/osfmk/kern/sched_prim.c:2420
```

and

```
BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Slack
```

I also ran an EtreCheck report but it didn't mention Slack in it's possible causes (report summary attached). Any help in interpreting appreciated!

```
Diagnostics Information (past 7-30 days):
    2021-07-14 12:15:09 Kernel Panic (2 times)
        Details:
            panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8000bccc3f): "thread_invoke: preemption_lev
            el -1, possible cause: unlocking an unlocked mutex or spinlock"@/Build
            Root/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4903.278.51/osfmk/ke
            rn/sched_prim.c:2420
        3rd party kernel extensions:
            com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower
            com.avast.FileShield
            com.avast.PacketForwarder
            com.intel.kext.intelhaxm
            com.logmein.hamachi
            com.motu.driver.FireWireAudio
            com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.snowleopard
            org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv
            org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp
            org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt
            org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB

    2021-07-13 01:01:52 signpost_reporter - High CPU Use
        Executable: /usr/libexec/signpost_reporter

    2021-07-08 14:28:41 mdsync - High CPU Use (2 times)
        Executable: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdsync
```

Comment: Get rid of Soundflower, or at least replace it with a version made this decade. Also lose the paceap, which is more than likely from a cracked pro audio plugin & way too old for Mojave. Check intelhaxm is current [or if you need it at all]. Same for motu - that kext name sounds like the stuff they were using in the late noughties [& does a 2015 MBP even *have* firewire?]. They abandoned some products & kept others current, check at motu. The others ought to be OK so long as they were current at Mojave.

Comment: @Tetsujin MOTU kext is needed to run 8Pre FW via Thunderbolt to FW adapter. It's officially supported up through Mojave and this is the most recent version. paceap is from a (purchased, not cracked) plugin that required iLok but I don't use it anymore so will dump it. Will check the others, thanks. Any thoughts as to whether Slack is a red herring?

Comment: OK, no worries. I wasn't sure about the motu, it just looked well out of date. Same for paceap, they tend to be released 'per macOS' & need frequent updates over the years. I think the latest is called 'eden', to no longer tie it to one specific OS release. They were always really flaky if you had the wrong one. idk if Slack is a red herring tbh.

Comment: @Tetsujin Just to follow up, after removing kexts and still having random panics, I stopped using the Slack app and switched to the web interface. No more crashes -- it's been several weeks. Thanks and cheers.